# Places API sometimes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

On the website I am working on, we use the Places Autocomplete API on multiple pages. But sometimes, it looks like the service is down for a few hours, and then it starts working again. This has happened quite often over the last few days.

Here is how I'm loading the API :

`<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places&language=en"></script>`

Anyone has encountered this problem?

Comment: You probably need to get an API key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you're going over quota and need to get an API key. When a new day ticks over there's a new daily quota, which is why you'd see it working intermittently.

Get a key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key